# Jupyter server personal files

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

Novice here

So yesterday I downloaded Anaconda, and from there I clicked on launch Jupyter. That opened the web browser where I could see all the files in my computer. That is a concern for me as I figure that other people can also access that.

I managed to shut down the server via the terminal by using a command control-x or something along those lines. My questions are:

- Does Jupyter somehow save that data somewhere?
- Is that data still accessible to somebody else even though I shut down the server?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default a Jupyter Notebook server runs on localhost, which is only reachable from the local machine. In addition, it generates a unique token that you need to connect. So nobody else from a different machine can see your data.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.